# MVC Partial View renders but does not execute Razor code

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I have an AJAX call returning a partial view, but it only returns the `<div>` part of the view. My guess is that it's ignoring the Razor code. This seems like an immensely stupid issue and I cannot figure it out for the life of me.

Here's my partial view, in its entirety:

```
<div id="result">
@foreach (var log in Model)
{
    <br />
    <h3><b>Log ID: </b>@log.ID</h3>
    <h3><b>Log Time: </b>@log.LogTime</h3>
    <h3><b>Event Type: </b>@log.EventType</h3>
    <h3><b>Message: </b>@log.Message</h3>
    <h3><a href="Log/Details/@log.ID">View Details/Delete Entry</a></h3>
}
</div>
```

All that the AJAX call is returning is:

```
<div id="result">
</div>
```

This is the return statement inside the controller being invoked by the AJAX call (YES, it hits):

```
return PartialView("MyPartial", MyModel);
```

I've tried adding `@model IEnumerable<MyType>` at the top, but that made no difference.

On my complete view, I'm calling `@Html.Partial("MyPartial", Model)` and STILL, only the outer `<div>` tags are showing up in my page source.

This is quite a frustrating issue, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you make sure to build after making changes in your `c#`? Have you tried setting a breakpoint there in order to ensure `Model` is not null? `@Html.Partial("MyPartial", Model)` will take the current Model and pass it to the partial without hitting the controller, what is in `Model` at that point? Does your partial have, or not have, an `@model` declaration? Do the `@model` declarations in both child and parent match? Sorry for all the questions, but these are some of the areas I feel could affect your `foreach` loop not iterating. I guarantee that any valid razor code is executing though.

Comment: Can you also show the code where the ajax call is made, and where the ajax options are defined if done through the helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the Model collection is empty?
Try to add another element like `@Model.Count` inside the div, but outside the foreach.

Alternatively, put a breakpoint in the controller to make sure the collection contains at least one element.

That will test the assumption that the foreach isn't executing due to an empty collection